# What Missing in my JavaScript Code ? It does not work inside a WordPress Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

JavaScript, jQuery Experts,

I have the following coding, It work perfect when i check it in JSFiddle, but it does not work when I insert it in a WordPress post, so what should I do?

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/m1aaaqo9/11/

WordPrss page link: https://kahoothack.net/kahoot-flood/

Note: The login button does not work in WordPress post neither it accept password and username. It seems the JavaScript is not working there. So how to fix it?

Check my WordPress post and below see the login box why it is not working. Thanks

**HTML Part**

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Part**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name= $("#name").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                $("#Required").html('All Feild Are Required').css('color','red');
            }else if(name == 'admin' && pass == '123'){
                 $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
             }else{
                 $("#error").html('User Are Not Valid');
             }
        });
    });
```

**CSS Part**

```
h1{
            font-size:25px;
            margin:10px 0;
        }
        .form-box{
            border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
            padding:20px;
        }
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name= $("#name").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                $("#Required").html('All Feild Are Required').css('color','red');
            }else if(name == 'admin' && pass == '123'){
                 $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="https://kahoothack.net">Click</a>').css('color','green');
             }else{
                 $("#error").html('User Are Not Valid');
             }
        });
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation Form</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do? What's it doing wrong?

Comment: Carcigenicate, The login button work in JSFIDDLE when put username as admin and password as 123, then when click on it then it show successful  message as you try in fiddle, but when i past the same coding in wordpress post, it does not work the login button not working neither it accept the password and user name...it seems that only the html part is showing there..not working javascript..so how to fix it..so it work same as it in jsfiddle..

Comment: You link to jQuery (a version with known security issues which isn't supported any more!) but not to your own script.

Comment: Quentin could please kindly share the coding with me again with jsfiddle if you can fix it..please help me here..do at your own side if you can how to fix it..thanks

Comment: Any errors in browser dev tools console? Most wordpress themes use `jQuery.noConflict()` which means global `$` isn't `jQuery` any more and will throw error

Comment: @charlietfl no,..can i share the wordpress page with you so you can check why it is not working ?

Comment: can you tell us where/how you added your scripts and the code above in wp?

Comment: @Manjunath here<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name= $("#name").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                $("#Required").html('All Feild Are Required').css('color','red');
            }else if(name == 'admin' && pass == '123'){
                 $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
             }else{
                 $("#error").html('User Are Not Valid');
             }
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @Manjunath i also updated the post..i added the script in post at the bottom,...check above my wordpress post and see in page source how it is added

Comment: Where did u add this code? i mean in which file?

Comment: @Manjunath inside the post where i write content at the bottom...

Comment: This error is showing in the browser console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` @ line 121. You should not add the js code inside the WordPress post. You can either put the JS code in the footer.php, call it using `wp_footer` or use a plugin for inserting code.

Comment: oh sry you can't just include like that in wp. you can use custom css js plugin to include your custom scripts or you can use shortcode plugins if you are not familiar with wp coding

Comment: but i also added some other script in other pages that work fine..but this theme also provide option for javascript at the bottom i past the coding also there but not working..could you check it in your wordpress page ?

Comment: @SkyRocket Can you share the links of the other pages?

Comment: @KashifRafique you can check it here too..https://kahoothack.net/contact-us/ when i put admin and password 123 and click on login it does not show successful instead it add # to the same page link and reload the page.

Comment: @SkyRocket This page is also showing `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` error on line 146. The JS code seems to be added in the footer not inside the post. By the way what's the purpose of this login form?

Comment: @KashifRafique check the same coding in blogger page where everything clean but it also not working there here is link: https://testjsvascripts.blogspot.com/p/javascript-test.html

Comment: @SkyRocket This is also generating JS error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` on line 2659.

Comment: @KashifRafique i added jquery script into the blogger page it now work,..but cannot in wordpress...i added this script <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>  now check the blogger page and check the login by putting the admin and password 123 it now worked but cannot in wordpress..https://testjsvascripts.blogspot.com/p/javascript-test.html

Comment: @SkyRocket Check my answer below. Tested and working solution on my WordPress with Twenty Seventeen theme.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to handle form submission in JavaScript, bind to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` event of the submit button. Further, you need to cancel the default form submission event like so:

```
$('#form').submit(function handler(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // Cancel default form submission
     const data = new FormData(this); // JQuery binds `this` to the form DOMNode
     console.log("process the form data", data);
});
```

Keep in mind that form submission does not require JS by default. You're sometimes better off just submitting to the server and letting it do its work.

Comment: please could you now share the complete javascript code with me...So i try it...how to do it..thanks

Comment: No go...you're the programmer :-)

Comment: I have wasted almost 24 hours not working....could you kindly spend 1,2 minutes to gather coding you share so i add it then..thanks

Comment: if you are talking then i have to do the stuff in wordpress..the same coding also not working in blogger post too...check it here: https://testjsvascripts.blogspot.com/p/javascript-test.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove all HTML, CSS and JS/jQuery code from your post and put just the following code inside your post:

```
<div class="container lh-custom">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Name:admin</span>
    <span>password:123</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form action="#" method="post" class="form-box" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Login"/>
                    <span id="Required" style="color:#ff0000;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="error" style="color:#ff0000"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Save your post.

Then put following code in your current theme's (Aspire Pro) functions.php:

```
/* Add custom jQuery and CSS */
function lh_add_custom_js_css(){
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var pass = $("#pass").val();
                if(name == '' || pass == ''){
                    $("#Required").html("All Feild Are Required").css("color","red");
                }else if(name == "admin" && pass == "123"){
                     $("#form").html('<h4>User Login Successfully</h4><a href="">Back</a>').css('color','green');
                }else{
                     $("#error").html("User Are Not Valid");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .lh-custom h1{
            font-size:25px;
            margin:10px 0;
        }
        .lh-custom .form-box{
            border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
            padding:20px;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'lh_add_custom_js_css' );
```

Save functions.php file and check the page again.

Comment: Thanks bundles may you live long..your code worked finally as per your instructions! May you get the most successful man: thanks brother again...wish you all the best

Comment: Glad to be a helping hand. Would you mind considering the upvote and accepting my answer?

Comment: why not i already voted but it says reputation less than 15 will be recorded and cannot tickmark it..